# VS Code, F8 shows command history

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running VS Code 1.68.1 on Windows 11.

When the terminal pane has focus and I press F8 the previously used commands are shown, just like if I press up arrow. There are no keyboard shortcuts that does this.

This becomes a problem when I press F8 in the editor pane to run a selection of PowerShell code, the code runs, but then the same command is shown after the cursor in the terminal pane.

What could cause this?

For example, I have this code selected:

```
Write-Output 'Hello'
```

This is what happens in the terminal pane:

```
PS C:\Temp>
PS C:\Temp> Write-Output 'Hello'
Hello
PS C:\Temp> Write-Output 'Hello'
```

What is causing the Write-Output command to be shown a second time?

Comment: I have tried to change the keyboard shortcut to F4 for 'PowerShell: Run Selection', with the same result. So it is probably not a collision of shortcuts.

Comment: `F8` shortcut is from powershell not vscode so you probably won't be able to change it. But if changing it from `F8` to `F4` still shows previously executed line it might be a bug in the powershell extension, you can checkout the issues present on github maybe you will find something there. https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is an issue with vscode powershell extension v2022.6.1, the command repeating thing stop once I reverted the extension back to v2022.5.1...

Comment: Thanks Kleber! It is a problem with the Powershell addin, a fix is included in a PR, so I guess it will be fixed. Reverting to 2022.5.1 does solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i could fix that for me with enable the setting "Force Clear Scrollback Buffer" in the settings of powershell extension.

[VSCode Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoDDX.png)